# How to position JavaFx chart axis tickmark label

Tags: javafx-2

I'm pretty new to JavaFx.  I'm using a LineChart with a NumberAxis, and would like to change the position of the tick mark labels on the X axis, so that the tick mark labels are on the same line as the tick mark, and immediately to the right of the tick mark (and not centered directly beneath the tick mark)?  I don't see an obvious way to get this done.  It looks there is no control over the tick mark label position, except rotation.  I can create my own axis extending from the ValueAxis, but still I don't see a way to get at repositioning the tick mark labels.

Comment: Seems, yes, you will have to do extension...

Comment: @AlexanderKirov, I have a similar question on the position of an axis label that I want to modify. I see that I have to create a class that extends the original one (NumberAxis). But I get a "you cannot extend a final class" => am I missing something? How do you do?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to extend Chart to do this.

public abstractclass YourCustomXYChart extends Chart {